# Mapping @ManyToMany collection to collection of ids

Tags: java, mapstruct

I'm trying to map a JPA entity (`Recipe`) containing a collection of different `Product`s with a many-to-many association.

```
@Data
public class Recipe {
    private String id;
    //ManyToMany
    private Set<Product> products;
}
```

```
@Data
public class Product {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    //ManyToMany
    private Set<Recipe> recipes;
}
```

For the result, I'm only interested in the ids of those entities:

```
@Data
public class RecipeDTO {
    private String id;
    private Set<String> productIds;
}
```

So that leads to this mapper:

```
@Mapper
public interface RecipeMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "productIds", source = "products.id")
    RecipeDTO mapToDto(Recipe recipe);
}
```

Now, this doesn't work:

```
RecipeMapper.java:8: error: No property named "products.id" exists in source parameter(s). Did you mean "products.empty"?
    @Mapping(target = "productIds", source = "products.id")
                                             ^
```

Too bad. I was hoping to make it work like this, but it makes sense that it doesn't work. My next idea was to define a method to map a `Product` to a String, extracting its `id`, possibly `@Named`. Using something like `String mapToProductId(Product product)`, but the `@Mapping` annotation needs a `target`, which in this case would be the String (value) itself. I'm not sure if this is at all possible, I've looked at the documentation, the examples, the user group, and Stackoverflow, to no avail.

So, at this point, it would be easier to implement the whole mapping of `Recipe` myself, but I can't help but feel like I'm missing something. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I guess you should remane `products.id` to `product.id`. because there is no Products class, it is Product

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you need to implement`String mapToProductId(Product product)` and change "products.id " to "products" like:

```
@Mapper
public interface RecipeMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "productIds", source = "products")
    RecipeDTO mapToDto(Recipe recipe);

    default String mapToProductId(Product product) {
      return product.getId();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like it. I was hoping there was another way though, because in my usecase there are multiple of these collections (not just the one like in this example), so I'd have to implement each one, as well as the other way around, instead of using something like `@InheritInverseConfiguration`. At this point, it makes more sense to simply implement the entire mapper myself.

Comment: I suppose you can implement `ProductToIdMapper` with the implementation of `mapToProductId` method and then reuse the mapper in other places. Something like `@Mapper(uses = ProductToIdMapper.class)`.
Also I can't see how you can map String to Product then with `@InheritInverseConfiguration`, just set an id to empty object